# If object count greater than 1000 , display 1k in template view

Tags: python, django

I am very new in django. I am trying to do something like facebook ,where by if the number of comments on a picture is equal to 1000, instead of displaying 1000comments , i want 1k comments is displayed to the users.
I did something like this

view code

```
def DisplayPic(request,slug):
    # this get the object of the image 
    AdvertObj=get_object_or_404(Images,slug=slug)
    #to get  comment objects belonging to the image .Company stands for image instance 
    comments=ProductComments.objects.all().filter(company=AdvertObj) 
    #get the total comment count belonging to the image 
    commentcount=comments.count()
    # now verify if comment count is greater than 1000 
    # if comment count greater than 1000 or equal to 1000 , 1K+ comments display instead of showing 1000+ comments 1kcomments displayed
    if commentcount>=1000:
        r=commentcount/1000 #(to reduce values to be displayed to users in 1k+)
        return r
     context{'count':commentcount}
     template_name='templat.html'
     return render(request,template_name,context)
```

I get an error when ever commentcount is greater than or equals to 1000 counts
** error 'float' object has no attribute 'get'**

I know i my approach is completely wrong . Please help me . My end result is to display if commentcount is 1000 , instead of displaying 1000comments to users , 1kcomments is displayed . Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `commentcount = '{0:.1f}k'.format(commentcount/1000)` in your if statement.

Comment: Have a look at [`contrib.humanize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/humanize/). Note however, that  [`intword`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#intword) does not start below 1 million. I'd suggest to use template tags for this kind of formatting and `humanize` is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you somuch . I will have to try this

Comment: The main issue is `return r`. You want to assign it to commentcount inside your if condition

Comment: Definitely recommend that you look at `humanize` as suggested by dhke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function appears to return an integer value if `commentcount>=1000` -> I believe you are looking to assign this to commentcount; not return the int value.

Change your if condition to:

```
if commentcount>=1000:
    commentcount /= 1000 #(to reduce values to be displayed to users in 1k+)

 context{'count':commentcount}
 template_name='templat.html'
 return render(request,template_name,context)
```

This way; you always return the `render` function's output; which will always be a HttpResponse.